# What's the best way to persist Mongo aggregate results?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Using the results of this query:

```js
const results = db.collection.aggregate([
  { $match: { _id: { in: ids } } },
  { $set: {
    field: {
      $cond: {
        if: someCondition,
        then: true,
        else: "$field"
      }
    }
  } }
])
```

What's the best way to persist `results`? Using `updateMany`? But how?
The results of the aggregation is an array of `db.collection` documents. It has to be an optimised solution for this?

I was expecting Mongo to have something like:

```js
// (WARNING: This code is not valid)
db.collection.updateDocuments(arrayOfUpdatedDocuments)
```

NOTE: I cannot use `$out` because we're not using Mongo 4.4 so I cannot write in the same collection being queried.

Comment: Use $merge or $out to another collection. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @D.SM  I want to query and update a collection in the most efficient way.

Comment: `$out` is available starting in MongoDB 2.6, unless what you want is to create the collection in another database, in that case starting at MongoDB 4.4.

Are you using an older version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that `bulkWrite` lets you send a whole document on each update. So, this will be a good options:

```js
    db.collection.bulkWrite(
      results.map((doc) => {
        return {
          updateOne: {
            filter: { _id: doc._id },
            update: doc,
          },
        };
      })
    )
```